# store string data in rrd database

Tags: rrdtool, rrd

is it possible to store string data in rrd database

for example ,

if i want to store

```
Employee Name 
Employee Address
Employee Phone
Employee Mac Addr
```

in rrd database using py-rrdtool , if it is possible then how to do that can any give me road map to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rrdtool stores time series numerical data only, use sqlite or in python maybe even something simple like pickle to store your text data ... if the data is related to an rrd file, store it in a pickle with a different extension right next to the coresponding rrd file.

Comment: This could make a very useful feature however. Even for network montiroing, I could include the ifAlias string into each check and display it on the graph.